# Multiple SSL certificates Apache2

Tags: apache, ssl, certificate, virtualhost

secure.dynaccount.com (Thawte cert)
http://certlogik.com/sslchecker/secure.dynaccount.com/

api.dynaccount.com (self-signed)
http://certlogik.com/sslchecker/api.dynaccount.com/

## httpd.conf

```
# Thawte certified
<VirtualHost 88.198.55.138:443>
    ServerName secure.dynaccount.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dynaccount.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/ini/ssl/secure.dynaccount.com/private.key
    SSLCertificateFile /var/ini/ssl/secure.dynaccount.com/public.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile /var/ini/ssl/secure.dynaccount.com/intermediate.crt
    SSLVerifyDepth 1
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP
</VirtualHost>

# self-signed
<VirtualHost 88.198.55.154:443>
    ServerName api.dynaccount.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dynaccount.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/ini/ssl/api.dynaccount.com/private.key
    SSLCertificateFile /var/ini/ssl/api.dynaccount.com/public.crt
    SSLVerifyDepth 0
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Not a programming question -> voted to move to ServerFault.

Answer (score 2):

Did you read Apache HTTP docs?

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html

> Name-based virtual hosting cannot be used with SSL secure servers
>   because of the nature of the SSL protocol.

You can have one SSL host per IP.

Reason?

SSL connection parameters are set per-vhosts, but must be negotiated before httpd reads host HTTP header.

That give a sense, isn't it?

UPDATE:

Change SSLCACertificateFile to SSLCertificateChainFile and provide correct format of file according to [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatechainfile) or disable client cert verification at all

Comment: You don't mentioned that you use SNI.Do you have SNI-capable apache running?

Comment: I'm not sure.. Have updated my question with openssl info.. I don't know how to check if the TLS extension is enabled and the other two prerequisites..

Comment: Based on docs OpenSSL must have enable-tlsext option compiled in.From your openssl version I can't see it, so probably not.

Comment: ok, I have now an additional IP available.. But when I restart the server I get an error.. if api.dynaccount.com is commented out there are no errors

Comment: Check my updated answer about SSLCertificateChainFile and SSLVerifyDepth

Comment: SSLCertificateChainFile is changed.. `<VirtualHost 88.198.55.138:443>` `<VirtualHost 88.198.55.154:443>`

Comment: Modify http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#loglevel in global config to debug and post your error log

Comment: From log I see that both vhost certificates show CN as 'secure.dynaccount.com', but it should match ServerName directive.Also set this directive in first vhost to secure.dynaccount.com and in second vhost to api.dynaccount.com.Server alias is not needed.

Comment: ok.. you were talking about `SSLVerifyDepth`? secure.dynaccount.com is a Thawte cert and api.dynaccount.com is self-signed

Comment: have updated my question.. api.dynaccount.com is using the same cert as secure.dynaccount.com

Answer (score -1):

Your problem here is that you have twice the same ServerName.

In your 2nd VHost, you should have `ServerName api.dynaccount.com` and no `ServerAlias`

I'm not sure it's the problem, but give it a try :)

---

edit:
For the `Server could not reliably resolve server name` error, you have to define a ServerName in httpd.conf (not in VirtualHost, that will be the default server name)

Comment: The 2 notices? I also have it, don't worry to much about this one. I think it's because you use an asterisk to define VirtualHost (as I do), and Apache doesn't likes it too much. So far he understood it anyway, so I keep using it & it works.

Comment: @haltanbush > Apache won't even start.. So I can't ignore it

Comment: [Wed Mar 28 11:00:35 2012] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using dynaccount.com for ServerName